# How to make div responsive to screen resolution's?

Tags: html, css

My div works fine (occupies all the area) only if the screen size equals my default screen resolution. Otherwise i get this [image]

How to make it responsive to screen resizing?

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;  
}

header{
 width: auto;
 background: url(pictures/heading-zebras-2.png) no-repeat 50% 0;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 450px;
}

header h1{
 float: left;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 40px 0 34px 43px;
 width: 437px;
}

.tel {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 height: 60px;
 padding: 30px 87px 0 0;
 width: cover;
}

.tel li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.tel a{
 font: 28pt/0.64 "Consolas", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;
 font-size: 87.5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div><h1><a href="homepage.html"><img src="pictures/header-banner-text.png" alt="banner"></a></h1></div>
    <div class="tel">
  <nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href=".html" title="">AMERICAS</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html" title="">AFRICA</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html" title="">EUROPE</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html" title="">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html" title="">ASIA</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your fixed `h1` width that is creating this problem. If you are after responsive design, try to use fixed values as little as possible.

```css
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
   list-style: none;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: url(pictures/heading-zebras-2.png) no-repeat 50% 0;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 450px;
 display: flex;
}

#banner-div {
 flex: 1;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

header h1 {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0 34px 43px;
 float: left;
}

.tel {
 flex: 4;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 30px 87px 0 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tel li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.tel a {
 font: 28pt/0.64 "Consolas", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;
 font-size: 87.5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div id="banner-div">
     <h1>
   <a href="homepage.html">
    <img src="pictures/header-banner-text.png" alt="banner">
   </a>
  </h1>
 </div>
 <div class="tel">
     <nav>
         <ul>
             <li><a href=".html" title="">AMERICAS</a></li>
             <li><a href=".html" title="">AFRICA</a></li>
             <li><a href=".html" title="">EUROPE</a></li>
                <li><a href=".html" title="">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
             <li><a href=".html" title="">ASIA</a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: But what if i want to show `tel` block inline with `header h1` so that each one has differnet height?

Comment: Updated the code so it shows banner and menu inline. I suggest you take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what u want to achive, just make steps like below:

1. U need to remove float into selector h1 (we want to keep hight of our logo div)
2. Create div which keep your nav and logo into one ( I gave him class .all), we want background on whole content.
3. On the end just remove background-color from  header h1, and .tel

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;  
}
.all {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
header{
 width: auto;
 background: url(pictures/heading-zebras-2.png) no-repeat 50% 0;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 450px;
  
}

header h1{
 padding: 40px 0 34px 43px;
 width: 437px;
}

.tel {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 30px 87px 0 0;
 width: cover;
}

.tel li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.tel a{
 font: 28pt/0.64 "Consolas", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;
 font-size: 87.5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="all">
    <div>
      <h1>
        <a href="homepage.html"><img src="pictures/header-banner-text.png" alt="banner"></a>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tel">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href=".html" title="">AMERICAS</a></li>
            <li><a href=".html" title="">AFRICA</a></li>
            <li><a href=".html" title="">EUROPE</a></li>
            <li><a href=".html" title="">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
            <li><a href=".html" title="">ASIA</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```